# What does "haircut" mean here?

Tags: investing, terminology

I'm reading [WHAT HAS WORKED IN INVESTING](https://www8.gsb.columbia.edu/sites/valueinvesting/files/files/what_has_worked_all.pdf), and quote

> When liquidation value appraisals are made, the estimated
> "haircut" on accounts receivable and inventory is often recouped or exceeded by the estimated value of a
> company's real estate and equipment

What does haircut mean here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In investing and other financial contexts, a haircut means [a reduction applied to the value of an asset](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/ecb/educational/explainers/tell-me-more/html/haircuts.en.html).  This means, in this case, that they reduce the value of accounts receivable and inventory (as the liquidation procedure will aim to settle/sell things quickly, and so at less of a value than they might otherwise get).